# Length of png file is undefined on expo build:ios

Tags: ios, react-native, build, expo

I am building my react native app for ios (`expo build:ios`) and I have no errors on the app on dev mode.

But when I build the app for iOS, I get an error on a png :

*Building optimized bundles and generating sourcemaps...
Starting Metro Bundler
**src/assets/Registrered/ligne.png:** Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')*

I'm quite speechless about this error and don't find anything online about it...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by upgrading expo